# Is there any point to the Courser Uniform?

Tags: fallout-4

I've been lugging around a Courser Uniform under the assumption that it would help me trespass undetected in...certain places.  However it seems like those places don't notice or care about what I'm wearing, and welcome me with open arms regardless.

Is there any point in having the Courser Uniform, or should I just trash it?

Additionally, is there any reason (apart from the obvious familial one) not to immediately go stalking through those certain places, killing anything that moves?  I mean the people there actually *mostly* seem nice, which makes it hard to want to massacre them all, but their methods are obscene and it's clear that they're hiding something.  Are there negative plot repercussions to wiping them all out on the first visit?  A simple yes/no will do for that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Courser uniform has some nice stats and looks OK, but has no additional benefits beyond the stats displayed and its appearance. It won't act as a disguise. Whether it is useful or not is largely down to what armors you already have.

As for murdering everybody, you could try but you're in a facility full of synths armed to the teeth. This action will also make you enemies of the Institute and lock you out of part of the story (which would rely on you being friends or neutral with the Institute) but not prevent you from completing the game via another ending.

Answer (score 3):

**The Courser Uniform is probably the best outfit that you can give your Settlers**, unless you want the hassle of equipping them with actual armor pieces (Which Army Fatigues, Military Fatigues, etc can be worn under, but the Courser Uniform cannot - so you'll want to use Fatigues instead and some Heavy version of any armor).

All the aforementioned clothing can be improved with ballistic weave, the Courser Uniform getting the highest values (which are second only to Maxson's Battlecoat and the Mechanist's Armor (both of which are unique)).

You can loot and purchase Courser Uniforms at the Institute and/or loot them from Coursers. Note that PAM of the Railroad will, at some point, give you missions to hunt down Coursers, so you can loot one for every such mission. You may also, on rare occasion, randomly encounter Coursers in some high-level areas.

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ballistic_weave

Answer (score 3):

If you consider that the courser uniform weighs only 15 units you might like dropping 40-60 units of weight simply for that switch alone. In addition, you get a bump in Endurance and Perception. The [Endurance](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Endurance#Fallout_4) boost will also give you more hit points.

I'm considering it now. My current set of pieces provides much more energy protection over the courser with Weave Mk5 but the ballistic bump is quite a big larger with the courser uniform so I'll have to keep my own ready in it's own container in case I want to return and switch. It's nice that even a small little Chem Cooler can hold infinite large items.